# java.text.ParseException: The date '2013-12-11T14:45:00.000-04:00' is not a valid Date Time Format

Tags: hl7-fhir

Class: org.hl7.fhir.instance.model.DateAndTime
method: setFraction(int fraction)

fails when fraction is 000. I see in the code

```
public void setFraction(int fraction) throws Exception {
    this.fraction = fraction;
    if (this.fraction == 0)
        throw new Exception("set 'fractions' before setting 'fraction'");
}
```

Is check "if (this.fraction == 0)" a mistake and should it be "if (this.fractions == 0)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely an error - meant to be this.fractions. Thanks

Committed now, posted to web soon